# jQuery .append() is not synchronized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to add a hover class on a div, and have a transition effect on it. But I need to append the element to the parent first, just to make it always on top of the others. This is a trick to simulate the z-index effect when z-index is not available (e.g. SVGs don't have z-index).

But in the example 1, the transition effect is not working. My assumption is that the addClass() happens before the element finishes appending. So the process is like this,

> call append() => add class to element => transition starts => append
>   element, and the current transition is cancelled => append() finish =>
>   no other transition happens

To prove my assumption, in the example 2 I use a setTimeout() call to wrap around the addClass(). And in this case, the transition works normally.

So is my assumption is correct? Is the solution in example 2 a neat solution to this problem? Please help, thanks!

```js
$('.inner').hover(function(){
    var item = $(this)
    item.parent().append(this);
    if ($('#sel').val() == "1") {
        item.addClass("hover");
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            item.addClass("hover");
        }, 0)
    }    
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

```css
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.inner.hover {
    transform: scale(1.1)
}
.outer {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner" style="left: 0px;">1</div>
    <div class="inner" style="left: 100px;">2</div>
    <div class="inner" style="left: 200px;">3</div>
</div>
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think it's less about the .append() being done, and more about the browser hasn't rendered the element yet. but that's not too far off from what you were saying.

Comment: why not do the transition in pure css without using jquery to add the hover class?  ie: inner:hover {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. The engine [removes the element from the DOM and adds it back](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) (`$.append` uses `appendChild`). That is why `setTimeout` is working properly.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should use appendChild.

Answer (score 1):

The below has the same effect without having to use jQuery.  Unless there is a particular reason to use jquery to add the hover effect.

```css
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.inner:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1)
}
.outer {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner" style="left: 0px;">1</div>
    <div class="inner" style="left: 100px;">2</div>
    <div class="inner" style="left: 200px;">3</div>
</div>
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a particular reason for this. Because I need to do the append trick to the SVG element. By doing so, in firefox the hover state will be lost. So I need to manually add hover class to the element.